# Unable to transform Angular v9's JavaScript error stack trace from its minified form on RollBar in local environment

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, rollbar

Just a little background about our app, we have been running our Angular frontend inside the docker container and have a shell script that is responsible to set the environment variables and build the frontend container with the required configuration. While building the frontend we also upload the minified files to our Rollbar server using the command as described in the RollBar docs. So, when we run our app in production we had the following commands to upload them to the Rollbar server. (Note minified_url holds the HTTP path of our app.

```
curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
  -F access_token={$RollBar_Access_Token}\
  -F version=$GIT_CURRENT_REVISION\
  -F minified_url=https://example.com/$MINIFIED_JS \
  -F source_map=@dist/webapp/${MINIFIED_JS}.map;
```

However now in order to replicate the behaviour in the local development environment, we  changed the minified_url to the path inside the container as shown below which points to our minified JS file inside the container(Note $MINIFIED_JS is the variable that holds the name of our minified Js file)

```
curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
  -F access_token={$RollBar_Access_Token}\
  -F version=$GIT_CURRENT_REVISION\
  -F minified_url=///front/dist/webapp/$MINIFIED_JS \
  -F source_map=@dist/webapp/${MINIFIED_JS}.map;
```

After trying this we were successfully able to upload the main.[hash].js file to the Rollbar Server and thought it is going to work fine until we saw the stack trace of an error after we made the above changes. Here is the stack trace. As we see it was unable to resolve it to the lines pointing to our source code thus making it difficult to debug in the local development environment.
[image]
As you see in the above image it says **"Source map was not available for some minified file"** which made us realize that why it failed to translate. So we went and checked which file it failed to upload and here is the screenshot for the same
[image]
So,  after many attempts, we thought of just uploading the failed file manually where we attached the source map it wanted, and we put URL as http://localhost/main.[hash].js and the appropriate GIT version of the source code. And yes thing started working fine and it was able to translate the error pointing to our source code.
Now, we want to know is there any way to do it through our shell script as we do in production so that we do not have to go through the manual process every time we work in the local environment with RollBar. Any help or leads appreciated.

Articles referred
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/debug-angular-apps-in-production-without-revealing-source-maps-ab4a235edd85
https://pusher.com/tutorials/error-handling-angular-part-4
https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/14/how-do-source-maps-work.html

Answer (score 1):

So, we figured out the answer to our question thanks to the RollBar support team as they guided us with the exact bash code needed to successfully transform the minified error to its source code form thus giving us exact line number in the source code where the error has occurred

The problem with our approach was that we were giving the path to the minified file inside our docker container which was not even looked upon by RollBar server, instead, Rollbar always looked for the file as [ //localhost/$MINIFIED_JS] in the local dev environment that's why you see in the second image above  //localhost/main.[hash].js  in red because RollBar tried to download that file but could not find it, thus leading to the failure. But once we replaced our minified_url path with //localhost/$MINIFIED_JS Rollbar no longer failed to download the file as we had provided the file to it. Here is the exact code we put :

```
curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
  -F access_token={$RollBar_Access_Token}\
  -F version=$GIT_CURRENT_REVISION\
  -F minified_url=//localhost/$MINIFIED_JS \
  -F source_map=@dist/webapp/${MINIFIED_JS}.map;
```

Remember: $MINIFIED_JS is the variable holding our minified file main.[hash].js. For your case you if you know the minified file name you will have to exactly put that name. Also, we have combined all the minified files into one file named main.[hash].js. If in your case if you have multiple minified files then you will have to upload each of them. Here is the awesome bash code to do upload multiple minified files using bash code( source of the code: https://michalzalecki.com/upload-source-maps-to-rollbar/)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Save a short git hash, must be run from a git
# repository (or a child directory)
version=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)

# Use the post_server_time access token, you can
# find one in your project access token settings
post_server_item=$ROLLBAR_POST_SERVER_ITEM

echo "Uploading source maps for version $version!"

# We upload a source map for each resulting JavaScript
# file; the path depends on your build config
for path in $(find dist -name "*.js"); do
  # URL of the JavaScript file on the web server
  url=https://example.com/${path}

  # a path to a corresponding source map file
  source_map="@$path.map"

  echo "Uploading source map for $url"

  curl --silent --show-error https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
    -F access_token=$post_server_item \
    -F version=$version \
    -F minified_url=$url \
    -F source_map=$source_map \
    > /dev/null
done
```